# Google Site - File Structure Replication with Auto Naming?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-workspace

I am creating a Google Site and creating a calendar within to link to a document for each and every day for every month of the year.
Are there any easier ways to replicate this structure for a calendar for multiple entities within?
Is there any easier way of linking each day within each month to the relevant Google Doc, and then replicate this for multiple entities?
Is there any way of pulling the file metadata i.e. folder location on Google Drive into the files automatically i.e. to confirm that the correct file is being accessed when the link in the Google Site is clicked?
Thanks ever so much
Kalps